# Android Studio Database inspector icon does not be shown

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

im  learning using room database in kotlin
but i cannot see database inspector icon in android studio.
has anyone any solution ?

[The picture of my android studtio home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7GJA.jpg)

Comment: 1. Where and how do you create a database instance 2. Also [do not upload pictures of code, here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database):

1. Run your app on an emulator or connected device running API level 26 or higher.
2. Select View > Tool Windows > App Inspection from the menu bar.
3. Select the Database Inspector tab.
4. Select the running app process from the dropdown menu.
5. The databases in the currently running app appear in the Databases pane. Expand the node for the database that you want to inspect.

Comment: when i click on app inspection , it shows this message : deploy your app to a device running api level 26 or higher or select a debuggable proccess to inspect.

Comment: Well, it is pretty self-explanatory, run the app on a device with Api level >= 26 and then you will be able to use the database inspector